# Find the intervals in which the function decreasing. $f(x)= \log{(1+x)}-{2x\over 1+x^2}$

Tags: real-analysis

$f(x)= \log{(1+x)}-{2x\over 1+x^2}$  find the intervals in which the function decreasing.

My solution: $$f'(x)={1\over 1+x}- {2(1-x^2) \over (1+x^2)^2} \\ ={x^4+2x^3+4x^2-2x-1 \over (1+x)(1+x^2)^2}$$
Since we need to find the interval for decreasing hence $f'(x)<0$.
Therefore, $${x^4+2x^3+4x^2-2x-1<0}$$
Now how to proceed to find the interval. Thanks for help.

Comment: Note that $f'(x)$ can also change its sign about its asymptote _i.e._, you have to consider the $1+x$ in the denominator for the sign as well.

Comment: For this question in particular, the roots are going to be very complicated. So, I'd suggest to reread the question from its source.

Comment: @ultralegend5385: $1+x> 0$ for all values of $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/find-the-intervals-in-which-the-functionfx-log-1-x-dfrac2x2/ @Chris

Comment: @ Jitendra Singh: that would be easy to find the interval but in this particular problem it'd be difficult to trace the interval.

Comment: @Chris: oh yes, seems like I need to not use SE while in bed.

Answer (score 1):

The first derivative must be less than zero for a function to be decreasing.
$f'(x)={x^4+2x^3+4x^2-2x-1 \over (1+x)(1+x^2)^2}$,
The system of inequalities must be resolved by:

$x^4+2x^3+4x^2-2x-1 <0$,

$x+1>0$,

for the existence of the logarithm in the real field.

In addition, it must be $x≠-1$.

The solution to the problem is as follows:
$x_{1}<x<x_{2}$,

$x_{1}=-\frac{\sqrt{6}\sqrt{3\sqrt{R}-S}}{6}+\frac{\sqrt{3T}}{6}-\frac{1}{2}$,

$x_{2}=+\frac{\sqrt{6}\sqrt{3\sqrt{R}-S}}{6}+\frac{\sqrt{3T}}{6}-\frac{1}{2}$;

the values of $R$, $S$, and $T$ are:

$R=4A^{1/3}+4B^{1/3}+4a^{1/3}+4b^{1/3}+1$,

$S=6C^{1/3}+6c^{1/3}+5$,

$T=12D^{1/3}+12d^{1/3}-5$;

and again

$A=\frac{4375}{5832}-\frac{125\sqrt{129}}{1944}$,
$a=\frac{4375}{5832}+\frac{125\sqrt{129}}{1944}$,

$B=\frac{2386}{729}-\frac{70\sqrt{129}}{243}$,
$b=\frac{2386}{729}+\frac{70\sqrt{129}}{243}$,

$C=\frac{35}{216}-\frac{\sqrt{129}}{72}$,
$c=\frac{35}{216}+\frac{\sqrt{129}}{72}$,

$D=C$,
$d=c$.